# Conditional probability problem in Elementary Probability Theory with Stochastic Processes

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

> There are two kinds of tubes in an electronic gadget. It will cease to
>   function if and only if one of each kind is defective. The probability
>   that there is a defective tube of the ﬁrst kind is .1; the probability
>   that there is a defective tube of the second kind is .2. It is known
>   that two tubes are defective, what is the probability that the gadget
>   still works?

This is from *Elementary Probability Theory with Stochastic Processes*, K.L.Chung.

My solution: the probablity that the gadget won't work is $\frac{0.1\times 0.2}{0.1^2+0.2^2+0.1\times 0.2} = \frac{2}{7}$, assuming that the defections are independent in this gadget. So the answer shall be $\frac{5}{7}$.

But the correct answer is $\frac{5}{9}$. So I assume that the $0.1\times 0.2$ term above should actually be doubled. But I can't account for the factor of 2. Could someone explain this to me? Thanks!

Comment: Hint: you have a coin with prob head=0.3 What is the probability that, if your throw two coins, we get a tail and a head?

Comment: If there are only two kinds of tubes and the probability that a defective tube is of type A is 0.1 then shouldn't it follow that the probability that a defective tube belongs to type B is 0.9 as a defective tube can either be of type A or type B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_{1}$be the first tube that breaks down and $X_{2}$ the second.
Then there are four possibilities:

(1) $X_{1}$ a tube of the first kind and $X_{2}$ is a tube of the
first kind. Unconditional probability: $0.01$

(2) $X_{1}$ a tube of the first kind and $X_{2}$ is a tube of the
second kind. Unconditional probability: $0.02$

(3) $X_{1}$ a tube of the second kind and $X_{2}$ is a tube of the
first kind. Unconditional probability: $0.02$

(4) $X_{1}$ a tube of the second kind and $X_{2}$ is a tube of the
second kind. Unconditional probability: $0.04$

Adding these probabilities gives $0.09$ and in the cases (1) and
(4) the gadget still works. This leads to conditional probability
$\frac{5}{9}$